# Two data sources and two outlets in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create something really simple with ember.js, and I'm getting badly lost between old examples, new examples, and extensive documentation.

I want to create an application with no functionality, that simply shows two sets of data in two columns. The real application uses JSON data from two different sources and is more complicated, but the problem reduces to getting the below to work:

```
<div id="appholder">
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet left}}
  {{outlet right}}
 </script>
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="left">
  <div id="left">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
 </script>
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="right">
  <div id="right">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
 </script>
</div>
```

and in the javascript something like

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#appholder'
});

App.LeftController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['left one', 'left two'];
  } 
});
App.RightController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['right one', 'right two'];
  } 
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
      this.render('left', {
        outlet: 'left',
        controller: 'left',
      });
      this.render('right', {
        outlet: 'right',
        controller: 'right',
      });
    }
});
```

to output the hoped for result, a left column with list entries from one data source and a right column with two entries from another column.

Could somebody ideally provide a js fiddle with the above adapted to working code? Any part of it can change, to use `{{render}}` or `{{view}}` in the templates and whatever the js should be.

Thank you for any help

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mifer/2/edit

Comment: put your code into here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ then share the link in your post... it would also be helpful to explain what is not working about your code... any errors?  We can give you suggestions and solutions, but dont expect someone to just do it for you.

Comment: @Grapho jsfiddle added, I've created all elements of a large dashboard application in ember using various remote data sources, but cannot find a way to output them all on the same page. Have tried multiple approaches and read multiple examples over the past several hours. Really stuck on something which seems incredibly simple. Any help at all would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dixaqopikiyi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

First in order to use a function as a property, you must make it a computed property with the `property()` function:

```
App.LeftController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['left one', 'left two'];
  }.property() 
});
```

Secondly, the `renderTemplate` code is in the wrong place. You put it in the `index` route but in reality it should be in the `application` route. If you had `{{outlet}}` in your `application` template, the index template would have been rendered into it. Then, if you had those two named outlets inside the index template, what you had would have almost worked (you need to call `this.render()` or `this._super()` whenever you use `renderTemplate` if you want the route template to render.

But, you have two named outlets which you want to manually render into inside of your application template. Hence:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render();
    this.render('left', {outlet: 'left', into: 'application'});
    this.render('right', {outlet: 'right', into: 'application'});
  }
});
```

Now [this next approach](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bicupabebani/1/edit) is how I tackle multiple models in my dashboard application. I am constantly needing to replace the sections of widgets so I use multiple named outlets. I've restructured your code so that the application template renders the index template into its single unnamed outlet.

Keys to this approach:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      left:  ['left one', 'left two'],
      right: ['right one', 'right two']
    });
  },
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model){
    this.render();
    this.render('left', {outlet: 'left', into: 'index', controller: 'left', model: model.left});
    this.render('right', {outlet: 'right', into: 'index', controller: 'right', model: model.right});
  }
});
```

Whenever you need to return multiple models, and you want your route to block until all models are returned, use `Ember.RSVP.hash`. You return multiple promises, each as properties of your returned `model`. RenderTemplate takes two parameters, `controller` and `model` so you access your model in the renderTemplate to manually pass the model into the controller of the template you are rendering.

As a slight [alternative](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kezotixalora/1/edit) to this approach, if you need to render multiple datasources on the page, but you do not ever need to dynamically replace the whole template backing one of the models (ie render once and done), you can use the `{{render}}` helper.

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
 <p>Index Template</p>
 {{render 'left' model.left}}
 {{render 'right' model.right}}
 </script>
```

The benefit of this code is that our `route` has simplified.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      left:  ['left one', 'left two'],
      right: ['right one', 'right two']
    });
  }
});
```

But, we have lost the ability to easily render something else here via action since we no longer have named outlets.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much, and also for any further edits on various ways to approach this :)

Comment: @MarkPfennig edits made. hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: thank you for all your help @sunrize920 - I found a slight nuance with the second example where model.left and model.right were both overriding model when using async data. Resolved the issues by removing `, model: model.left` and specifying `{{#each item in model.left}}` in the template. Here's the modified example using remote data http://emberjs.jsbin.com/koconu/1/edit